# Js Pagination error

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to perform a *pagination* where I need to display 5 rows every time. First 5 rows are displayed. On the second click, the next 5, the third rows no. 11-15, and so on. I need to display even if at least one row is there (after n clicks where totalRows mod 5 is less than 5). I do not get this.

```
function rightArrow()
{   
        pageCount = document.getElementById('pgCnt').value; //totalRows / 5
        totCount = document.getElementById('totCnt').value; //totalRows
        currPage = tempRows - pageCount + 2; //current set of rows
        document.getElementById('tempPage').value = tempPage;
        var m = totCount%5;

        if(pageCount != tempRows)
            m = 5;
        else
        {   m = (totCount % 5) - 1; 
            document.getElementById('rightArr').disabled = true; 
        }

        document.getElementById('pgCnt').value = document.getElementById('pgCnt').value - 1;

        for(i = 0; i < m;i++)
        {
            $.ajax({    
                type: "POST",
                url: "getEODRow.php",
                data: "page=" + currPage + "&row=" + i,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    var row = document.getElementById('chRecommend').insertRow(0);
                    temp = html.split(",");
                    for(j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                    {
                        str = temp[j].replace("\"","");
                        str = temp[j].replace("\"",'');
                        str = temp[j].replace("[",'');
                        col = row.insertCell(j);
                        col.innerHTML = str;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        currPage++;
}
```

Comment: Use modulus to determine if you need to start a new row (IE i%5)

Comment: A word of advice: get used to carefully declaring all your local variables with `var` ...

Comment: @ineedhelp - here's another thing to conside. I don't know what the deal is with getting the wrong *number* of rows, but be aware that there's no guarantee that the AJAX responses will come back in the order that the requests were issued.  Therefore, even if you were getting the right *number* of lines, they could very well end up out of proper order.  You'd be much better off fetching 5 lines at a time anyway.

Comment: but what if there are 46 rows and i need to print the 46th row separately

Comment: Then send back only whole pages at a time, so 5 rows before the last page and 1–5 rows on the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is pretty much dead, but I came across it looking for something else, and I figured I'd toss an answer at it. Since it's not a critical issue, I went ahead and reworked everything you've got here plus a lot of code that you didn't choose to include.

```javascript
// App namespace
var MyApp = {Paging: {}};

// Paging Controller
MyApp.Paging.Controller = function(){ this.init.apply(this,arguments);};
MyApp.Paging.Controller.prototype =
{
    // Initializer gets everything hooked up
    init: function()
    {
        $.log("Initializing Paging Controller.")
        // Get all the nodes we'll need
        this.totCntNode = document.getElementById("totCnt");
        this.pgCntNode = document.getElementById("pgCnt");
        this.currMinNode = document.getElementById("currMin");
        this.currMaxNode = document.getElementById("currMax");
        this.prevPageButton = document.getElementById("prevPageButton");
        this.nextPageButton = document.getElementById("nextPageButton");

        this.pageContainer = document.getElementById("pageOfItems");
        // Mimic table's .insertRow to make row adding easy
        this.pageContainer.insertRow = function() {
            var row = document.createElement("div");
            row.className = "row clearfix";
            for (var i = 0; i < MyApp.Paging.Model.itemsPerRow; i++)
            {
                var cell = document.createElement("span");
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            this.appendChild(row);
            return row;
        };

        // Attach listeners to the next and previous buttons
        this.prevPageButton.onclick = this.showPrevPage.bind(this);
        this.nextPageButton.onclick = this.showNextPage.bind(this);

        // Update the display for the first time
        this.updatePageInfo();
    },

    // Run this whenever the model has changed and needs to update the display
    updatePageInfo: function()
    {
        // Get info about what page we're on
        var currentPage = MyApp.Paging.Model.currentPage,
            totalPages = MyApp.Paging.Model.getTotalPages(),
            itemCount = MyApp.Paging.Model.itemCount,
            pageSize = MyApp.Paging.Model.getPageSize(),
            rowsPerPage = MyApp.Paging.Model.rowsPerPage,
            rowsOnThisPage = Math.ceil(MyApp.Paging.Model.getItemsOnPage(currentPage)/MyApp.Paging.Model.itemsPerRow);

        // Clear out previous page data
        while (this.pageContainer.children.length > 0)
        {
            this.pageContainer.removeChild(this.pageContainer.children[0]);
        }

        // Add space for the new page data
        for (var rowInd = 0; rowInd < rowsOnThisPage ; rowInd++)
        {
            this.pageContainer.insertRow();
        }

        $.log("Loading Page " + currentPage + ".");

        // Request the data via ajax for each row
        for(var i = 0; i < rowsOnThisPage ; i++)
        {
            $.ajax({    
                type: MyApp.Paging.Model.queryType,
                url: MyApp.Paging.Model.queryURI,
                data: MyApp.Paging.Model.getQueryData(currentPage, i),
                success: function(pageNum, rowNum, result)
                {
                    // Don't serve data from the wrong page
                    if (pageNum !== MyApp.Paging.Model.currentPage) return;

                    // When we get the data back, put it into the correct container
                    // regardless of when it was received
                    var row = this.pageContainer.children[rowNum],
                        temp = result.replace(/[\["]/g,"").split(","),
                        str = "";
                    for(var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++)
                    {
                        row.children[j].innerHTML = temp[j];
                    }
                }.bind(this, currentPage, i)
            });
        }

        // Update the informational bits under the items
        this.totCntNode.textContent = itemCount;
        this.pgCntNode.textContent = totalPages;
        var min = currentPage * (pageSize ) + 1;
        this.currMinNode.textContent = min;
        this.currMaxNode.textContent = Math.min(min + pageSize - 1, itemCount);

        // Disable the prev page button if there are no previous pages
        if (currentPage <= 0)
        {
            if (this.prevPageButton.className.indexOf("disabled") < 0)
            {
                this.prevPageButton.className += " disabled";
            }
        }
        // Enable the prev page button if there are previous pages
        else
        {
            if (this.prevPageButton.className.indexOf("disabled") > -1)
            {
                this.prevPageButton.className = this.prevPageButton.className.replace(/(?:^|\s+)disabled(?!\S)/g, "");
            }
        }

        // Disable the next page button if there are next pages
        if (currentPage + 1 >= totalPages)
        {
            if (this.nextPageButton.className.indexOf("disabled") < 0)
            {
                this.nextPageButton.className += " disabled";
            }
        }
        // Enable the next page button if there are next pages
        else
        {
            if (this.nextPageButton.className.indexOf("disabled") > -1)
            {
                this.nextPageButton.className = this.nextPageButton.className.replace(/(?:^|\s+)disabled(?!\S)/g, "");
            }
        }

    },

    // This is called when the next page button is clicked. 
    showNextPage: function()
    {
        if (MyApp.Paging.Model.currentPage + 1 >= MyApp.Paging.Model.getTotalPages())
        {
            // Shouldn't have been able to activate this anyway
        }
        else
        {
            MyApp.Paging.Model.currentPage++;

            this.updatePageInfo();
        }
        return false;
    },

    // This is called when the prev page button is clicked
    showPrevPage: function()
    {
        if (MyApp.Paging.Model.currentPage <= 0)
        {
            // Shouldn't have been able to activate this anyway
        }
        else
        {
            MyApp.Paging.Model.currentPage--;

            this.updatePageInfo();
        }
        return false;
    }
};

// I typically expect an object like this to be created by the server and dropped dynamically onto the page
MyApp.Paging.Model = {
    itemCount: 140,
    itemsPerRow: 9,
    rowsPerPage: 5,
    currentPage: 0,

    queryType: "POST",
    queryURI: "getEODRow.php",
    queryDataFormat: "page={itemPage}&row={itemRow}",

    getTotalPages: function() {
        with(MyApp.Paging.Model) {
            return Math.ceil(itemCount/(itemsPerRow*rowsPerPage));
        }
    },
    getPageSize: function() {
        with(MyApp.Paging.Model) {
            return itemsPerRow * rowsPerPage;
        }
    },
    getItemsOnPage: function(pageNum) {
        with(MyApp.Paging.Model) {
            return Math.min(((pageNum+1) * getPageSize()), itemCount) - pageNum*getPageSize();
        }
    },
    getItemsInRow: function(pageNum, rowNum) {
        with(MyApp.Paging.Model) {
            var onPage = getItemsOnPage(pageNum);
            return Math.min((rowNum+1)*itemsPerRow, onPage) - rowNum*itemsPerRow;
        }
    },
    getQueryData: function(itemPage, itemRow) {
        with(MyApp.Paging.Model) {
            var data = queryDataFormat;
            data = data.replace(/{itemPage}/gi, itemPage);
            data = data.replace(/{itemRow}/gi, itemRow);
            return data;
        }
    }
};
```

So, whenever the page is loaded, with an onload handler or whatever, you would create and hang onto a singleton instance of the Paging Controller.

```javascript
MyApp.Paging.Controller.instance = new MyApp.Paging.Controller();
```

This should handle issues with Ajax calls returning out of order as well as partial pages of data and partial rows within those pages.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2UJH8/8/